# Couldn't find Type for class 'com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject'

Tags: java, html, libgdx, cross-platform

Ok, so I made a simple game in libgdx (Android Studio). It works on desktop as well as on Android but in html throws this error :

> Uncaught Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find Type for class 'com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject'

The only code that uses `RectangleMapObject` in my code is this:

```
for(MapObject mapObject: tiledMap.getLayers().get(1).getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)){
        Rectangle rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject)mapObject).getRectangle();
        createGround(rectangle.getX()/ 70f, rectangle.getY() / 70f, rectangle.getWidth() / 70f, rectangle.getHeight()/70f);
}
```

I spent almost two days trying to make it work and found nothing. If someone knows the solution to this problem, Its cause or anything like that i would realy appriciate some help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection on gwt requires some massaging to work

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection#gwt

---

Add this to your `GdxDefinition.gwt.xml` :

```
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.badlogic.gdx.maps.objects.RectangleMapObject" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it took me a while to understand how to use theese reflections in my code but it finaly worked.  Hope you'll have a nice day :)

Comment: I have more or less the same problem and add extend configuration property didn't help me. There is something else to do??

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme Can you show me your error log, It'll be great if you create one new topic for your problem, you can reference this thread in your question. I'll try to help you there.

Comment: Here is my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817992/export-libgdx-project-to-html-did-you-forget-to-inherit-a-required-module)